# С FILE with UTF8 chars Correcting Inacceptable Record (Read/Check/OverWrite)

Tags: c, winapi

I need to correct inacceptable data to acceptable data. Like 1-12 months. And days in month as supposed to be 28-31.
input.txt

```
IBM HC-486 1995 11 12 228 Иванов IBM HC-476 1990 1 42 218 Васильев
```

code
Lab.cpp

```
#include "Lab.h"
#include <stdio.h>      //FILE
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>      //getch
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
struct Computer
{
    wchar_t mark[11];
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    unsigned char numroom;
    wchar_t lastname[20];
};
void input()
{
    FILE *inputFile, *outputFile;
    fopen_s(&outputFile, "output.dat", "wb");
    fopen_s(&inputFile, "input.txt", "r");
    fseek(outputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    Computer c;
    while (fgetws(c.mark, 12, inputFile))
    {
        StrTrimW(c.mark, L" ");
        fscanf_s(inputFile, "%d", &c.year);
        fscanf_s(inputFile, "%i", &c.month);
        fscanf_s(inputFile, "%i", &c.day);
        fscanf_s(inputFile, "%hhu", &c.numroom);
        fwscanf_s(inputFile, L"%s", c.lastname, _countof(c.lastname));
        fwrite(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile);
    }
    _fcloseall();
    return;
}
void find()
{
    FILE *outputFile;
    fopen_s(&outputFile, "output.dat", "rb+");
    fseek(outputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    Computer c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile))
    {
        if (c.year == 1995 && wcscmp(L"IBM HC-486", c.mark) == 0)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\nmark = %s year = %i month = %i day = %i numroom = %i lastname = %s", 
                c.mark, c.year, c.month, c.day, c.numroom, c.lastname);
            _getch();
            _fcloseall();
            return;
        }
    }
    wprintf_s(L"\nНе найдена запись с маркой IBM HC-486 и годом 1995!");
    _getch();
    _fcloseall();
    return;
}

int getdays(int year, int month)
{
    int days = 0;
    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        days = 30;
    else if (month == 2)
    {
        bool leapyear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
        if (leapyear == 0)
            days = 28;
        else
            days = 29;
    }
    else
        days = 31;
    return days;
}

void correction()
{
    FILE* outputFile;
    fopen_s(&outputFile, "output.dat", "rb+");
    fseek(outputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    Computer c;
    long item = 0;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile))
    {
        while (c.month < 1 || c.month > 12)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\nmark = %s year = %i month = %i day = %i numroom = %i lastname = %s",
                c.mark, c.year, c.month, c.day, c.numroom, c.lastname);
            wprintf_s(L"\n%s%i", L"Некорректный номер месяца \nПожалуйста введите другой номер месяца:", c.month);
            scanf_s("%i", &c.month);
            fseek(outputFile, item * sizeof(struct Computer), 0);
            fwrite(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile);
        }
        while (c.day < 1 || c.day > getdays(c.year, c.month))
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\nmark = %s year = %i month = %i day = %i numroom = %i lastname = %s",
                c.mark, c.year, c.month, c.day, c.numroom, c.lastname);
            wprintf_s(L"\n%s%i", L"Некорректный номер дня\nПожалуйста введите другой номер дня:", c.day);
            scanf_s("%i", &c.day);
            fseek(outputFile, item * sizeof(struct Computer), 0);
            fwrite(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile);
        }
        item += 1;
    }
    _getch();
    _fcloseall();
    return;
}
void print()
{
    FILE* outputFile;
    fopen_s(&outputFile, "output.dat", "rb+");
    fseek(outputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    Computer c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"mark = %s year = %d month = %i day = %i numroom = %i lastname = %s",
            c.mark, c.year, c.month, c.day, c.numroom, c.lastname);
    }
    _getch();
    _fcloseall();
    return;
}
```

Lab.h

```
#pragma once
    void input();
    void find();
    int getdays(int year, int month);
    void correction();
    void print();
```

Lab6.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>  
#include "Lab.h"
int main()
{
    //_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x20000);
    SetConsoleCP(65001);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    input();
    print();
    _getch();
    find();
    correction();
    //print();
    return 0;
}
```

result of program:

```
mark = IBM HC-486 year = 1995 month = 11 day = 12 numroom = 228 lastname = Ивановmark = IBM HC-476 year = 1990 month = 1
 day = 42 numroom = 218 lastname = Васильев
mark = IBM HC-486 year = 1995 month = 11 day = 12 numroom = 228 lastname = Иванов
mark = IBM HC-476 year = 1990 month = 1 day = 42 numroom = 218 lastname = Васильев
Неко�?�?ек�?н�?й номе�? дня
�?ожал�?йс�?а введи�?е д�?�?гой номе�? дня:42
```

as we can see encoding got corrupted, i do not know what to do actually, how to fix encoding.
also i type 1/2/3/4 and it says wrong goes back to while body. but supposed to eat it.
Im feeling awkward using :

```
fseek(outputFile, item * sizeof(struct Computer), 0);
item += 1;
```

because it might be different length, i do not know what better to use.

off-by-ones` production :

```
fgetws(c.mark, 12, inputFile);
```

kinda i wont grab a next record because it has a space i grab all with excluding one symbol when use

```
fgetws(c.mark, 11, inputFile)
```

Comment: C *or* C++. Which one? This looks like 100% C code.

Comment: I am attempting to use C. But those headers makes me feel awkward like
```#include "Shlwapi.h"```

Comment: These buffer sizes are absolutely puny and you have a number of off-by-one errors. Try and be a bit more generous in the sizing or use dynamic length strings instead.

Comment: What's "awkward" about that other than the strange inclusion of a capital letter in your file?

Comment: ```#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")```

Comment: What about that?

Comment: Im just worried does it has any C++ right now. Because I kinda made .cpp project after all. My homework task is about C.

Comment: I don't see any C++-specific code in here. If you want to do this in C++ you might have an easier time of it, as C is notoriously fussy when it comes to C strings. C++ has things like [`std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which is a lot easier to use in practice. If you're making a C DLL this might not be an option.

Comment: Fine so how may I fix encoding. at correcting code its like ```_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x20000);``` helps but i get other things encoded wrong. how may i fix off-by-ones via C way. Worst experience is that teacher asked to not use strings. Use char[] wchar_t[].
And also I need fix that ```item += 1``` since records are not same length.
Maybe some boost library solution. Duh?

Comment: What happens if you change input.txt to say "IBM HC-486 1995 11 12 228 Некорректн IBM HC-476 1990 1 42 218 Васильев".  It seems to fail when writing a р or т, so I'm wondering if there would be a difference reading these from a file rather than being within your source code...

Comment: If you do this and the first line of output is OK, it suggests the problem is in reading your string in the source code: L"Некорректный номер дня\nПожалуйста введите другой номер дня:", but that the rest is OK.  I'm not familiar enough to suggest how to fix that directly, but if you were to load this (and the other error messages) from a messages.txt file it would probably avoid the problem (as it appears that reading files and outputting is all working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also i type 1/2/3/4 and it says wrong goes back to while body

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-160#generic-text-routine-mappings):

> When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening
> call to either **fflush** or to a file-positioning function.

So you need to add `fflush` to prevent endless loops.

> we can see encoding got corrupted, i do not know what to do actually.

I think this is the console's limited support for Unicode, I think you can use `_setmode` to adjust the console's output mode.

This is the modified code:

```
while (fread(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile))
{
    while (c.month < 1 || c.month > 12)
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\nmark = %s year = %i month = %i day = %i numroom = %i lastname = %s",
            c.mark, c.year, c.month, c.day, c.numroom, c.lastname);
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
        wprintf_s(L"\n%s%i", L"Некорректный номер месяца \nПожалуйста введите другой номер месяца:", c.month);
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
        scanf_s("%i", &c.month);
        fseek(outputFile, item * sizeof(struct Computer), 0);
        fwrite(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile);
        fflush();
    }
    while (c.day < 1 || c.day > getdays(c.year, c.month))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\nmark = %s year = %i month = %i day = %i numroom = %i lastname = %s",
            c.mark, c.year, c.month, c.day, c.numroom, c.lastname);
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
        wprintf_s(L"\n%s%i", L"Некорректный номер дня\nПожалуйста введите другой номер дня:", c.day);
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
        scanf_s("%i", &c.day);
        fseek(outputFile, item * sizeof(struct Computer), 0);
        fwrite(&c, sizeof(struct Computer), 1, outputFile);
        fflush();
    }
    item += 1;
}
```

Comment: I solved by ```SetConsoleCP(1251);     SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);```
and resaving in 1251 encoding, via Save As button... But thanks.